# Azure ADAL Refresh id_token

Tags: owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal

We are developing a multi-tenant web application. Our tenants will be using Windows Azure Active Directory for authentication. We are using OWIN OpenIdConnect middleware to authenticate users. The response we receive after authentication process has id_token and authorization code.

We also want to get the refresh token so that we can acquire new tokens once the id_token expires. Therefore in AuthorizationCodeReceived handler we use AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode method in ADAL library to acquire the refresh token. The response contains id_token, access_token and refresh_token.

We then subsequently use refersh_token to get the new id_token however the response contain only renewed  access_token but not a renewed id_token. Is it possible to refresh id_token or we can only refresh access_token? The code snipped for Authorization code received handler is shown as below.

```cs
AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
{
    string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + "/";
    var code = context.Code;
    string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Password"];
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
    string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    MAuthenticationContext authContext = new MAuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantID), null);
    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                code, new Uri(appBaseUrl), credential, "https://graph.windows.net");

    AuthenticationResult refreshTokenResult = authContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshToken(result.RefreshToken, credential);

    return Task.FromResult(0);
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you cannot use a refresh_token to renew an id_token because an id_token represents user authentication, information that cannot be refreshed without the user present. The way to refresh an id_token is described in the Session Management draft of OpenID Connect (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) i.e. by sending the user (agent) off to the authorization endpoint again with an authentication request that may include "prompt=none" if you want no user interaction but just check with the OP for an existing SSO session.

The Session Management capability as described in the draft spec is supported by Azure AD. If you want to synchronize the OP session with your application session that is the way to go. OTOH you may choose to have an application session that independent of the OP session, using it's own session timeout and duration, in which case there's no reason to refresh the id_token. The id_token is then only use to bootstrap the application session which then lives on it's own.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I wanted to refresh id_token is I would be calling services with id_token in the Authorization header. Since the lifetime of token is 3600 seconds, I would need to again get the id_token for subsequent requests. For the web application itself, the id_token act as a bootstrapper.

Comment: The backend service could/should be an OpenID Connect client in itself if you care about the lifetime of the id_token and login semantics.  If it is just about passing user identity in a standardized structure (JWT) then the backend could treat it as a plain JWT and ignore the expiry, assuming that the caller is authenticated in some way.

Answer (score 3):

Also: the AcquireTokenByRefreshToken is really a manual fallback in case there's something in ADAL's automatic cache management that you don't want to execute. In general every call to AcquireToken* (apart from AcquireTokenByRefreshToken) **will** use the refresh token automatically if there's need and a valid one in cache. Unless you are really in special cases, I would advise against ever using AcquireTokenByRefreshToken

Comment: I replaced call to AcquireTokenByRefreshToken  with AcquireToken and I observed in fiddler that subsequent calls to AcquireToken get s a renewed token and does not pick it from token cache. "         result = authContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", credential, new UserAssertion(context.JwtSecurityToken.RawData));"

Comment: Gaurav, in your code you initialize authenticationcontext with a "null" as the cache. That indicates that you don't want to use any cache, hence he refresh token is lost. You have two options: one is using the default- don't pass anything there and Adal will use its OOB inmemory cache - and the other is to pass a custom cache, like we do in our samples, which allows you to pick any persistence storage you like. We have various samples under github.com/azureadsamples featuring custom cache classes

Comment: @vibronet would AcquireTokenSilent do that?

Comment: Acquiretokensilent uses the cache, yes.