# Azure Active Directory JWT for API authentication within Angular 4

Tags: angular, azure, jwt, azure-active-directory

I currently have 2 web apps(app services) setup on azure.  The first one is an angular 4 website the second one is a .net core 2.0 restful api.  I have CORs setup for the ui to talk to the api perfectly.  The only issue is there isn't any security around this API.

I am attempting to utilize the azure AD JWT token to be part of an authorize attribute within the API but the problem is the API can't validate the token since I don't have the secret key that azure is using to create the JWT token to begin with.  Also I am getting the token from /.auth/me.  Does anyone have any advice on how best to solve this problem?

Is there an api endpoint on azure that I can hit to get a valid JWT token for the current logged in user?  I noticed the /.auth/me one expires after an hour and the user is forced to visit /.auth/login/aad/callback in order to refresh the tokens.

I would love to know the best strategy to solve this, if it includes adal, msal, etc.  Also links to code would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use [ADAL for Javascript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) in your angular 4 Web App to retrieve the `id_token` or `access_token`, then using the relevant token to access your .NET Core 2.0 restful API. For your angular app, you could still use the build-in authentication/authorization provided by Azure App Service without changing your code.

For your .NET Core 2.0 restful API, you could just leverage [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) (Easy Auth) provided by App Service or you could manually use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/) package in your project for JWT authentication. Detailed code snippet, you could follow [here](https://github.com/gianlucb/Demo_AAD.2tiers/tree/master/src/AAD.2tiers.Api).

Additionally, I would recommend you create each AAD app for your front-end web app and Api web app.

Comment: How do I refresh the id_token via adal?

Comment: You could not refresh the id_token just as the access_token does,  your client user may need to login again, details you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288107/azure-adal-refresh-id-token).

Comment: If you need to validate the lifetime of token in your Api,  you could use `access_token`, from [AuthenticationContext.prototype.getCachedToken](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js) , you could find that if the user has the active session with AAD, adal.js would automatically renew the access_token for you, and you could follow [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/).

Comment: do I need an azure ad policy?  I am attempting to follow these examples but my organization limits our azure access so I am unable to create a policy.  I still haven't been able to validate whether a JWT was given to me from azure AD since I don't have the private key and I keep receiving  AuthenticationFailed: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from

Comment: You could use the public key to validate the access token, details you could follow [How to Validate the Access Token Issued by Microsoft Azure AD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/practice-sharing/2016/03/22/office-365-dev-how-to-validate-the-access-token-issued-by-microsoft-azure-ad/).

Comment: Per my understanding, the authentication middleware would help you to validate the token's signature, if you want to specify more advanced options for how JWT tokens will be validated, you may need to use `JwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters`, details you could follow [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/). Moreover, you could provide details (code snippet,etc) for us to narrow this issue.

Comment: Here is the code that I am currently using along with the error I am running into.

Comment: services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {           options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
          .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
          {
              jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
              jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
              jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
              {
                  OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
              };
          });

Comment: private Task AuthenticationFailed(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.AuthenticationFailedContext arg)
        {
            // For debugging purposes only!
            var s = $"AuthenticationFailed: {arg.Exception.Message}";
            arg.Response.ContentLength = s.Length;
            arg.Response.Body.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s), 0, s.Length);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

Comment: "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Tenant": "companyname.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "actualclientid", // test environment
    "Policy": "b2c_1_siup",

    "ScopeRead": "ppkpi-test.read",
    "ScopeWrite": "ppkpi-test.write"
  },

Comment: we don't have a policy setup and I don't have access to set one up but I wrote that in anyways.  Maybe that is the issue?  Is this code correct?

Comment: Are you talking about Azure AD B2C tenant? If you follow [An ASP.NET Core 2.0 web API with Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi/), you need to set up your policy. Or if you use Azure AD tenant, you could follow [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/tree/master/TodoListService) and configure `jwtOptions.Authority`  to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>`.

Comment: Currently using the tenant id I believe and I had requested a policy since that was the only way I saw it.  I will try this.